# uget with aria2 plugin

Tags: uget

I have read that `uget` with aria2 plugin enabled is the best downloader. So I tried.

I downloaded `uget` from the Ubuntu Software Center and also installed aria2 from the terminal.

Then I opened `uget` and opened Settings > Plugin section and activated "Enable aria2 plugin". My arguments read: `--enable-rpc=true -D --check-certificate=false`

Then when I clicked OK, it replied:

```
Failed to connect to aria2.
```

Is aria2 shutdown? Or did the aria2 launch fail?

I also tried some commands from web:

```
roshan@roshan-Aspire-4736Z:~$ aria2c --enable-rpc=true --check-certificate=false --disable-ipv6

2013-09-07 09:42:08.483317 ERROR - IPv4 RPC: failed to bind port 6800
Exception: [SocketCore.cc:308] errorCode=1 Failed to bind a socket, cause: Address already in use

2013-09-07 09:42:08.483629 ERROR - Exception caught
Exception: [DownloadEngineFactory.cc:181] errorCode=1 Failed to setup RPC server
```

Then I opened YouTube and tried to download a video. It won't download and at the bottom there was this message:

```
Message: aria2.getVersion result error
```

Please help me with this. I really need t have Aria2 plugin working.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Type this command in terminal:

```
aria2c --daemon --enable-rpc=true
```

for more detail go to this [link](http://lordamit.blogspot.in/2012/09/aria2c-enable-rpc-error-failed-to-bind.html?showComment=1400953471693).

Answer (score 1):

" i downloaded uget from ubuntu software center and..."

There is your problem. Canonical seems to hate uGet...no idea why but Ubuntu never has an updated version. The USC has version 1.8.2 and the current version is 1.10.3

Go to the official uGet site at http://uGetdm.com and download a DEB file for the Ubuntu version you use or install the PPA.

Uninstall the USC version first...to ensure proper install of the current version.

Comment: @ Michael :i removed my existing uget and installed latest version for 12.04 lts version . But still it says  : Failed to connect to aria2. Is aria2 shutdown? or aria2 launch failed.

Comment: think i have to wait for uget2 version. feeling sad..

Comment: I don't see why you would have to wait. uGet2 isn't need to make the plugin work. I no longer use Ubuntu myself but I used to and have tested uGet on every version and it works fine. - please go to the official Forum for further support as I might forget to check this site. http://ugetdm.com/forum - in the forum post please provide the exact error you are receiving now and how you installed 1.10.3 (ppa or deb file)

Comment: @Braiam why did you remove my mention of being a team member? I am on the uGet project team.

Comment: Check this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/213575 I should have removed more, but I will leave it to you.

Comment: I didn't make a signature at least not on purpose in a sense of a signature used in multiple places but I see the issue and have corrected it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I have my own answer in uGet 1.10.4 in Ubuntu 14.04 with aria2c version 1.18:

1. You must specify your own RPC port. In my example, 9299. This port
   number is must not being used by another process.
2. Then you should add `--enable-rpc=true --rpc-listen-port=9299` to the **arguments**.
3. You may specify additional argument such as `--check=certificate=false`.

To proof this, I ran uGet via console. Then I can see any output from aria2 in my console.

[image]

**Result**

It works. uGet and aria2 finally work together. I've been waiting for ~3 months for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution to exact same issue was this:

In UGet settings under plug-in tab change argument to this:
--enable-rpc=true

Then restart Uget and  aria2 should be working.
Uget version I use is 1.10.3.

[image: Screnshot UGet settings for aria2]

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Address already in use` is telling you that `localhost:6800` is occupied by some other programs. You have 2 options to solve it:
1. Find out the program which is occupying `localhost:6800`, change its port;
2. Change aria2's port, e.g. 6801.